# Using current_page? to add "active" class to nav links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Goal**

Apply a different class to the nav links to show which page the user is currently on.

**Approach**

view:

```
  <div>
    <%= link_to "Work", work_path, class: active_class(work_path) %>
    <%= link_to "About", about_path, class: active_class(about_path) %>
  </div>
```

helper:

```
    def active_class(link_path)
        current_page?(link_path ) ? "active" : ""
    end
```

routes:

```
  root 'pages#work'
```

**Outcome**

- "active" class IS NOT applied to "Work" link on "/" (FAIL) --> how do I correct this?
- "active" class IS applied to "Work" link on "/work" (SUCCESS)
- "active" class IS applied to "About" link on "/about" (SUCCESS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this:

```
def active_class(*paths)
  "active" if paths.any? { |path| current_page?(link_path) }
end
```

You can pass `root_path` if you need

```
<%= link_to "Work", work_path, class: active_class(work_path, root_path) %>
<%= link_to "About", work_path, class: active_class(about_path) %>
```

Comment: Change `current_page?(link_path)` to `current_page?(path)` and it works. Thanks so much!